# How to iterate arraylist from inner loop in that way every time will point next address element

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

There are two for loops and I want to iterate inner loop array in that way, every time will point next address element. How I can do that?

I have used below code after iterating first time from inner loop its break but i want to point next address of element when will iterate second time.

```
ArrayList<String> location;
ArrayList<String> distanceInMiles;

for (String strloc : location){
    for (int i = 0; i < distanceInMiles.size(); i++){
        String strDist = distanceInMiles.get(i);
        System.out.println("For Location :" + strloc + "Zip code 30303" + "Distance in Miles:" + strDist);
        //When iterate second time i want to point i=1 instead of i=0 but its pointing to i = 0

        double value = Double.parseDouble(strDist);
        value++;
        distanceInMiles.set(i, String.valueOf(value));

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking - Either `for(int i=0;` -> `for(int i=1;` or `distanceInMiles.set(i,` -> `distanceInMiles.set(i+1,`. Please explain further.

Comment: It would be easier to us to help you if you create and post a [mcve] which (1) can compile and run as is and includes (2) the output you want as well as (3) the output you're currently getting.

Comment: inner loop are pointing to only first location of element for every iteration but i want to that when iterate inner loop second time then value of i should point to second address of element and so on

Comment: ArrayList<String> location;// [27292, 28301, 29203, 28310, , 37090, , 31705, 28310, 31705, , 42743]
ArrayList<String> distanceInMiles; [274.89, 326.50, 192.42, 312.53, 195.14, 155.74, 312.53, 155.74, 249.85]
//i want for 27292 should print 274.89 for 28301 should print 326.50 and so on.. but every time printing 274.89

Answer (score 1):

> I want to iterate inner loop array in that way, every time will point next address element.

I interpret this to mean that you want each iteration of the inner loop to also advance the outer loop as well.  If so, then just use a single loop here:

```
for (int i=0; i < location.size(); ++i) {
    String strloc = location.get(i);
    String strDist = distanceInMiles.get(i);
    String msg = "For Location :"+strloc+"Zip code 30303"+"Distance in Miles:"+strDist;
    System.out.println(msg);
    double value = Double.parseDouble(strDist);
    value++;
    distanceInMiles.set(i, String.valueOf(value));
}
```

This of course assumes that I read your question correctly, and that both lists are the same size (or you can live with partially using one of the lists).

Comment: ArrayList<String> location;// [27292, 28301, 29203, 28310, , 37090, , 31705, 28310, 31705, , 42743]
ArrayList<String> distanceInMiles; [274.89, 326.50, 192.42, 312.53, 195.14, 155.74, 312.53, 155.74, 249.85]
//i want for 27292 should print 274.89 for 28301 should print 326.50 and so on.. but every time printing 274.89

Comment: @manishkumar Did you actually bother to test my code?  I don't think this behavior should be happening.  Also, it helps if you provide us with a reproducible question, ideally with a demo setup somewhere.  This helps us to avoid guessing as to what you want.